# Testing length of inputed message with old message

Tags: c, visual-studio, string-length

I'm working on a program that asks me to enter a new message and replacing the old one, but I have to test if the message is longer than the last one. I would like to get answer that is similar to my program because this is a lesson I'm learning right now. It asks me to input size of new char, but when I test it, it takes my set size for testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void editedMessage(char* nmessage, int size){

    char newMessage[];
    printf("Enter a new message!\n");
    gets_s(newMessage, sizeof(newMessage));

    if (size > sizeof(newMessage)){
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(newMessage); i++){
            nmessage[i] = newMessage[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("New message is too long.\n\n");
    }

}

void main(){

    char message[] = "This is some message!";

    printf("Old message\n%s\n\n", message);

    editedMessage(message, sizeof(message));

    printf("New message\n\n%s\n\n", message);

}
```

EDIT: I edited next code but now says 'stack around the variable 'message' was corrupted'

```
char newMessage[256];
    printf("Enter a new message!\n");
    gets_s(newMessage, sizeof(newMessage));
    int len = strlen(newMessage);

    if (size > len){
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(newMessage); i++){
            nmessage[i] = newMessage[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try printing the value of that `sizeof(newMessage)` to see how much room you have for typing in another message? If so, what does that tell you about the definition `char newMessage[];`?

Comment: I need to test if new message is longer or not from old message

Comment: Whoa! I get that, but you won't even get that far.

Comment: Take a look on string.h and ```strlen```

Comment: Forgot to mention that ```strlen``` will take end of your message '\0' into account while ```sizeof``` will return your array size...

Comment: I edited next code but now it says 'stack around the variable 'message' was corrupted'
`char newMessage[256];
 printf("Enter a new message!\n");
 gets_s(newMessage, sizeof(newMessage));
 int len = strlen(newMessage);

 if (size > len){
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(newMessage); i++){
   nmessage[i] = newMessage[i];
  }
 }`

Comment: @WeatherVane `char something[];` doesn't even compile, at least for me.

Comment: @CoolGuy I agree with that, but I was recently told somewhere in comment that it produces an array of length 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane Umm. How can you say that when the code doesn't even compile?

Comment: @CoolGuy it was another commenter, who must have been using a different compiler. I use MSVC.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(newMessage); i++)` → `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the return type of `editedMessage` to `char*` and cut down it arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1000
char* editedMessage(char* oldMessage){

    char newMessage[MAX_LENGTH];
    printf("Enter a new message : ");
    fgets(newMessage,MAX_LENGTH,stdin);

    if (strlen(newMessage)<= strlen(oldMessage)){
        strcpy(oldMessage,newMessage);
    }
    else {
        printf("New message is too long.\n\n");
    }
return oldMessage; // In fact the value of oldMessage should have been changed if the new message is shorter in length
}

void main(){

    char message[MAX_LENGTH] = "This is some message!";

    printf("Old message : %s\n", message);

    editedMessage(message);

    /* Since we are dealing with pointers, note that I am not catching any
     * return values here. In essence any changes made to message in the 
     * editedMessage function is automatically effective in the main         
     * function.
     */


    printf("New message :%s\n", message);

}
```

Comment: This code is not working for me, it says 'Expression:  (L''Buffer is too small'' &&0).

Comment: That's a difficult task, since "locate the problem" often is a several-step operation with no definitive answer. In this case, the error tracking mechanism that gets you the farthest is just being careful when you handle static sized buffers

Comment: @AntonioGvardijan :  I guess the error is at the `strcpy` part. See the edit.. The `message[MAX_LENGTH]`  part is what I changed.